# Kafka 0.10.0.0 client consumer data loss when partition created in running application

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have one consumer in pritam_group which has assigned 2 partition test_a-0 and test_a-1.

When I run below command

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181 --partitions 5 --topic test_a
```

and then next command

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test_a
```

and enter data="This is message"

Then my consumer is never getting this message. Don't know why ?
and my consumer logs are getting these line after some minutes not just after I increased the partitions.

```
2017-01-11 08:51:31,631 +0100 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] (EJB default - 1) Revoking previously assigned partitions [test_a-1, test_a-0] for group pritam_group
2017-01-11 08:51:31,632 +0100 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] (EJB default - 1) (Re-)joining group pritam_group
2017-01-11 08:51:31,636 +0100 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] (EJB default - 1) Successfully joined group pritam_group with generation 2
2017-01-11 08:51:31,636 +0100 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] (EJB default - 1) Setting newly assigned partitions [test_a-1, test_a-3, test_a-2, test_a-4, test_a-0] for group pritam_group
```

Answer (score 0):

The consumer consumes data only from the assigned two partitions (test_a - 0, 1). Once you've created 3 more partitions in the existing topic. The new data might be pushed to the other partitions (2, 3, 4). So, the consumer won't receive that message.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the message that you produce is being sent to one of the new partitions before the consumer rebalances and is assigned these new partitions. When new partitions are assigned to your consumer, it doesn't get the message because you should have consumer config auto.offset.reset set to latest (default value). If you set this config to earliest you will get the message.

Comment: Is there any property in kafak so that after creating new partition zookeeper notify the consumers coordinator for that change at the same time as I am seeing some delay on consumer side

Comment: I think what you want is metadata.max.age.ms configuration in your consumer